# Genitive phrases for things located in a city

Tags: difference, sentence-structure

Which is better or correct?

- Universities of New York
- New York Universities
- The universities in New York

However, the city could be not well known as New York! like Sirjan

Comment: Your use of capitalization makes things more confusing.  We don't capitalize *university* unless it's a proper name, like **Harvard University**.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you mean by **belong to a location** in the question title.

If all you wish to express is their location, then **in** is clearer here since **of** can imply that the institutions are somehow tied to (funded, governed by) the city|state as a governing body.

If you wish to express an institutional relationship, then **of** is the preposition to choose.

P.S. But **of** does not unequivocally express an institutional relationship. University of Oz could merely be its name, and Oz might not govern it or fund it. However, **in** simply refers to location.